# Prestashop change all product quantity to 1

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5

Hello i want to change all product quantity on a prestashop to 1 the shop is selling old books and they have only 1 of each but before now it was running on undefined quantity so people ware able to buy a product multiple times so i was tasked with changing that. I guess it should be done in the DB but i am unable to make the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backup your database before you do anything.

You can use this query to set the quantity of all products to 1 if you do not use product attributes:

`UPDATE ps_stock_available SET quantity = 1`

Additionally in the back-office you should set `Allow ordering of out-of-stock products` to `No` and `Enable stock management` to `Yes`.

If some of your products have no quantity (-- or 0) after running the query then you can rebuild the stock with following queries:

1. `DELETE FROM ps_stock_available`
2. `INSERT INTO ps_stock_available SELECT NULL, id_product, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2 FROM ps_product`

Comment: The query that you posted changed some entries however i have quite a few still that in the product list are shown as -- and in the product info as 0 any idea why that is ?

Comment: @IvanVeselinovNedelchev Do you use product attributes (e.g. color)?

Comment: no i using simple products, only picture price and short info

Comment: @IvanVeselinovNedelchev Does `SELECT id_product FROM ps_stock_available WHERE depends_on_stock = 1` return any product ids?

Comment: @IvanVeselinovNedelchev When you run the following two queries do you recognize any difference between the products that are ok and those that aren't? `SELECT * FROM ps_product`, `SELECT * FROM ps_stock_available`?

Comment: yes the first one returns 18 612 entries and the second one returns 20 078 what does that mean ?

Comment: @IvanVeselinovNedelchev I am not sure yet. Does this query return any product ids? `SELECT id_product FROM ps_stock_available WHERE id_product_attribute != 0`

Comment: @IvanVeselinovNedelchev And this one? `SELECT quantity FROM ps_product WHERE quantity != 0`

Comment: This too returns empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62392/discussion-between-yenshirak-and-ivan-veselinov-nedelchev).

Comment: The information that you provided proved very helpfull